# when Expect binary in ubuntu PC i am getting error, solve and give suggestions

Tags: ubuntu, arm, expect, scp

when dealing with expect command in Linux getting the error.
Actually, writing code for SCP (file transfer over network ) passing password as argument in shell script using expect binary, it successfully cross Compiled without errors. But while running that binary getting this error

**channel type exp must define output proc when used for writer channel Aborted.**

Give your suggestions to solve this error
SAMPLE CODE WRITTEN FOR ARM

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn bash -c "scp  samplefile.zip 192.168.2.211:/root"
expect {
  -re ".*es.*o.*" {
    exp_send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "password\r"
  }
}
interact
```

Comment: show some code that produces this error please

Comment: Actually here Cross compilation of expect binary for arm using **timesys** patches using the source(http://repository.timesys.com/buildsources/e/expect/expect-5.43.0/) is done successfully.But it is showing error as like above post mentioned.